# Is there a way to deploy different Elasticsearch clusters in one host to demonstrate Cross Cluster Search?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, cluster-computing, docker-container

I have 3 different Elasticsearch containers (which I deploy by the next command `run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.2`)

I want to use them as 3 clusters with 1 node in every cluster. after that I defined 2 of them as a remote clusters for one cluster (port `9200` is the "master" and `9201` `9202` is the remote). to define it I use:

```
cluster:
    remote:
        cluster_one: 
            seeds: 127.0.0.1:9201
        cluster_two: 
            seeds: 127.0.0.1:9202
```

and I try to run the search

```
GET /cluster_one:twitter/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "user": "kimchy"
    }
  }
}
```

but it didn't work, I assume it related to the way I defined the clusters but I didn't find what I do wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#node-roles) tells us that :

```
Cross-cluster search and cross-cluster replication require the remote_cluster_client role.
```

Moreover, the [remote cluster](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/remote-clusters.html#sniff-mode) page tells us that

```
role: By default, any non-master-eligible node can act as a gateway node. Dedicated master nodes are never selected as gateway nodes.
```

Since all nodes have the roles `master` & `data` by default, no node can act as a gateway node and cross-cluster operations cannot work.

I got one working [there](https://github.com/loldebyte/elasticsearch_engineer_prep/blob/8c6d127a3d4ea3b00e1875f8efc9d62c4d1cf6dd/docker-compose.multicluster.yaml).

The static remote cluster definition needs to be done on every node in following clusters using either env variables (as I did in the provided example) or `elasticsearch.yml`.

The url you need to match against is the url to the docker service hosting the gateway node.

The port needs to match the remote node's [transport port](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/modules-network.html#common-network-settings).